# Python selenium clicking on checkbox if exits on page

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to work out the best way to use selenium to tick a check box, below is the checkbox code and the selenium code I'm using

```
<input size="30" type="checkbox" name="break" id="breakid" class="enterDetails">

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//id[contains(text(),'breakid')]/following-sibling::checkbox")
element.click()
```

I only want to run this code if the check box exists on the page so example would be run first script and only run second script if you see this checkbox on the page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and except to make sure that you are doing the process only if the element is present. i.e., for your above code you could use like as below,

```
try: 
     element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//id[contains(text(),'breakid')]/following-sibling::checkbox")
     element.click()
except: 
     print "Element is not found"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hoping that the given is working and here is the code that you can use for verifying that particular element s displayed on the screen. if it is displayed do this action

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//id[contains(text(),'breakid')]/following-sibling::checkbox")
if element.is_displayed():
    element.click()
else:
    print("not avalable")
```

Comment: At the moment it's showing selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n

Comment: If it is throwing the message as "NoSuchElementException:" that means unable to find the element. 

make sure that finding the element by xpath is correct. try to find the element Xpath by using firebug.